# Let $S = \{1,2,3,4\}. X, Y \in \mathcal{P}(S)$ and R be a relation $R(X,Y): |X \cap Y| = 1$. Is the relation R transitive?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I'm reading up on *Relations and Functions* with the book *Discrete Mathematics by G. Chartrand, P. Zhang* and one of the exercises there proposes that the relation R over $\mathcal{P}(S)$ where $R(X,Y): |X \cap Y| = 1$ is *symmetric only* — which I can make sense with since my mental model with this is that $(a, b) \in R$ never occurs because $|X \cap Y| = 1$ is only true when $|X|$ or $|Y|$ is 1, therefore only $(a,a) \in R$, thus the implication for symmetry is vacuously true.

My concern is that with my thinking of how the relation R is symmetric, then this can also mean that it's *transitive* as well, since $(a,b) \in R \land (b,c) \in R$ never occurs and therefore is vacuously true also.

Is my thinking correct? How is relation R symmetric only and why can't it be transitive as well?

*Edit*
Okay. I had $(a,a) \in R(X \cap Y, X \cap Y)$ in mind for whatever reason when I was thinking $(a, a) \in R$.

Comment: What do you mean by: "$(a,b) \in R$ never occurs?" Are you implying that $R$ is empty? The reason that this relation is symmetric is because $|X \cap Y| = 1 \implies |Y \cap X| = 1$ which means if $(X, Y) \in R$ then $(Y, X) \in R$.

Comment: @PedroAmaral Oh... Your implication makes much more sense then. I was thinking $(a,b) \notin R$ because R can only be provided with $(a,a)$ pairs since $|X \cap Y| = 1$ can only be true when either |X| or |Y| is 1.

Comment: Added my reasoning why I think $(a,b) \in R$ never occurs.

Comment: What on earth do you mean $|X\cap Y|=1$ only if $|X|$ or $|Y|$ is $1$?  Take $X= \{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{2,3\}$ then $X\cap Y = \{2\}$ and $|X\cap Y| = 1$.

Comment: @PedroAmaral Can you post your comment as an answer so I can flag it?

Comment: @fleablood Yea, you're right...

Comment: The only times $R(a,a)$ is if $|a| = 1$.  that's because $a \cap a = a$ and so nothing is excluded through intersection.  If $a,b$ aren't equal $R(a,b)$ has nothing to with either having only one element.  It has to do with them only having one element in common.  Or if you think of it another way:  Everything but one element is excluded in the intersection.  As nothing is excluded in a set intersected with itself that's a restriction on (a,a).  But not on any unequal (a,b).

Comment: @fleablood edited my question — I was thinking about the $X \cap Y$ when I mentioned $(a,b) \in R$, more specifically I was thinking $(a,a) \in R(X \cap Y, X \cap Y)$, which is *really* wrong I know, but it was what I thought at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have absolutely no idea why you think $|X\cap Y|$ only if $|X|$ or $|Y|$ is $1$.

Simple case $X=\{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{2,3\}$ then $X\cap Y = \{2\}|$ and $|X\cap Y| = 1$ and $R(X,Y)$.

Further more if $Z = \{3,4\}$ then $R(Y,Z)$ but $X\cap Z =\emptyset$ so $\not R(X,Z)$ even though $R(X,Y)$ and $R(Y,Z)$.  So not transitive.

....

Any way  $X \cap X = X$ so $R(X,X)$ only if $|X| = 1$.  So if $|X| \ne 1$ we do not have $R(X,X)$ so it is not reflexive.

$X\cap Y=Y\cap X$ so $|X\cap Y| = |Y\cap X|$ so $R(X,Y) \iff R(Y,X)$ so symmetry holds.

Transitivity:  There no way to determine $X\cap Z$ from $X\cap Y$ and $X\cap Z$.  It is certainly possible for $X$ and $Y$ to have only one thing in common and $Y$ and $Z$ to have one thing in common but $X$ and $Z$ to have nothing or many things in common.

Let $X = $ the prime natural numbers.  Let $Y = $ the even natural numbers.  And let $Z=$ then numbers between $11$ through $13$ inclusively.

$X \cap Y= \{2\}$.  $Y\cap Z=\{12\}$ and $X\cap Z = \{11,13\}$.  Not transitive.